# Laravel download pdf file stored in separate Laravel app

Tags: laravel, file, download, streaming

I have 2 Laravel(5.8) apps.  One is a user application, the other is more of an API.

The Api has pdfs stored in the storage directory, I need to be able to allow a user to download the pdfs in the other application.

Really got no clue how to send the file over from app to the other.

The user app makes an api to the api with relevant file ids and things (fine), just can't work out how to send the file back, and then download it on the other end.

Tried things like `return response()->stream($pdf)` on the api and `return response()->download($responeFromApiCall)` and loads of other things but really getting nowhere fast.

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laravel code you posted is basically correct, you can use one of `stream()`, `download()` or `file()` helper to serve a file.

## `file()`

Serve a file using a binary response, the most straightforward solution.

```php
// optional headers
$headers = [];
return response()->file(storage_path('myfile.zip'), $optionalHeaders);
```

You can also use your own absolute file path instead of the `storage_path` helper.

## `download()`

The download helper is similar to `file()`, but it also sets a `Content-Disposition` header which will result in a download-popup if you retrieve the file using your browser.

```php
$location = storage_path('myfiles/invoice_document.pdf');
// Optional: serve the file under a different filename:
$filename = 'mycustomfilename.pdf';
// optional headers
$headers = [];
return response()->download($location, $filename, $headers);
```

## `stream()`

The `stream()` helper is a bit more complex and results in reading and serving a file in chunks. This can be used for situations where the filesize is unknown (like passing through another incoming stream from an API). It results in a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header which indicates that the data stream is divided into a series of non-overlapping chunks:

```php
// optional status code
$status = 200;
// optional headers
$headers = [];
// The stream helper requires a callback:
return response()->stream(function() {
    // Load a file from storage.
    $stream = Storage::readStream('somebigfile.zip');
    fpassthru($stream);
    if(is_resource($stream)) {
        fclose($stream);
    }
}, $status, $headers);
```

**Note**: `Storage::readStream` takes the default storage disk as defined in `config/filesystems.php`. You can change disks using `Storage::disk('aws')->readStream(...)`.

---

## Retrieving your served file

Say your file is served under `GET example.com/file`, then another application can retrieve it with curl (assuming PHP). A popular wrapper for this would be `Guzzle`:

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$file_path = __DIR__ . '/received_file.pdf';
$response = $client->get('http://example.com/file', ['sink' => $file_path]);
```

You can derive the filename and extension from the request itself by the way.

If your frontend is javascript, then you can retrieve the file as well but this another component which I dont have one simple example for.

Comment: This is by the far the closest I have got, thank you.  You code examples are basically an exact replica of mine (with some tweaks).  I am now able to get a pdf file onto my user app using this guzzle sink technique, but it says the pdf is corrupt.  I'll keep playing about with it.

Comment: OK, I can't `return response()->stream($filePath)` i get this error >>> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::__construct() must be callable or null, string given, called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php on line 123.  Which is why my pdf on the user app end is corrupt, because the contents haven't been properly streamed into it.

Comment: i figured it out with your help.  I can use `return response()->file($filePath)` this along with the `sink` guzzle option successfully streams the file over to my user app. Thanks for your help.  If you were happy to update your answer a bit to change `stream` to `file` I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes my bad, the `stream()` helper is a bit more complex than simply passing a file location. `download()` gives you a download-popup in the browser (although this probably wont matter if you request it through php or javascript). `file()` might probably be the best choice

Comment: `response->download()` doesn't work.  Needs to be `response()->file()`

Comment: I have expanded the answer, may it be of future help.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you have two systems: user app and api. You want to serve a pdf from user app to the actual user. The user app does a call to api, which works fine. Your issue is converting the response of the api to a response which you can serve from your user app, correct?

In that case I'd say you want to proxy the response from the api via the user app to the user. I don't know what the connection between the user app and the api is, but if you use Guzzle you could look at [this answer I posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261255/7528944).

Comment: That's mostly right.  I want to server the pdf from the user app to the user, but the user app has to get the pdf from the api first.  I can connect to the api and work out which pdf to send back, I just don't know how to send it back from the api to the user app.  I don't think your link helps too much, the example link wants me to pay for a tutorial that might not even be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should follow to get the PDF:

1. Make an API call using AJAX ( you are probably already doing it ) from your public site ( User site ) to the API server, with file ID.
2. API server fetches the PDF, copy it to the public/users/ directory, generate the URL of that PDF file.
3. Send the URL as a response back to the User site. Using JS add a button/ link in the DOM, to that PDF file.

**Example**:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
var responseData = JSON.parse(response);
var result = responseData.result;
var pdf_path = responseData.pdf_path;
$(".nametag-loader").remove();
$(".pdf-download-wrapper").append("<a class='download-link' href='"+ pdf_path +"' target='_blank'>Download</a>");
```

});